# Python unit test class cannot find self

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following unit test case written in Python.

```
import unittest
import json
from rules import RULES

class RulesTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.rules = RULES()
        self.har_json = json.load(test.har)

    def test_get_total_request(self):
        length = self.rules.get_total_request(self.har_json)
        self.assertEqual(length, 484)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Upon execution it gives me the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "rules_test.py", line 10, in <module>
class RulesTest(unittest.TestCase):
File "rules_test.py", line 18, in RulesTest
self.assertEqual(length, 484)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Can anyone please tell me why python class is not able to find self.

Comment: I suspect you have an indentation error.

Comment: Yes that was the case fixing that its giving me `RulesTest has no attribute rules`. But rules is clearly a attribute

Comment: Change setup to setUp